# What is the difference between std::vector<int> and std::vector<int>*?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am curious about the difference between `std::vector<type>` and pointer to this `std::vector<type>*`. Is it the same thing?

Comment: Why do you think that in the first run? I assume that you see the difference for a primitive type, like between int and int*. Why do you think this is different with std::vector?

Answer (score 3):

No. They are different types. The pointer is just an address in memory which points to a vector of type (or null if you do not create one for it to point to). Dereferencing the pointer will get you the vector of type it points to (or undefined behavior if it doesn't point to anything).The sizeof the pointer type will just be enough to hold an address value in memory.

Example (assume myVector is a vector that looks like this: { 1, 2, 3 })

```
// pVector points to myVector but it is not myVector. It is the ADDRESS of myVector.
vector<int>* pVector = &myVector;

cout << pVector; // prints out some address in memory like 0x3847583 or whatever.

cout << (*pVector)[0]; // prints out 1 since you dereferenced the pointer
```

So basically, pVector is the address of myVector and *pVector and myVector evaluate to the same thing right now. But you could always make pVector point to a different vector or nothing at all (null).

```
pVector = &anotherVector; // now it points to a different vector
pVector = null; // now it points to nothing
```

Comment: The result of dereferencing `NULL` or `nullptr` (C++11 and later) is undefined behaviour, according to the C++ standard.   A "null reference exception" is an outcome with some particular implementations, but not others.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` after the type declaration means that you have declared a **pointer** which can point to an existing object but it isn't an object itself. If you declare a pointer you just allocate a small amount of memory (which is big enough to store an address), but if you declare an object you allocates memory to hold the entire content of that object.

**Note:** avoid to dereference a pointer which isn't points to an existing object.

```
std::vector<int>* vPointer;
vPointer->push_back(6);
```

The code above will cause an undefined behaviour.